# req.cookies get overwritten when make request using nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I'm trying to make a request to the express/nodejs backend using nextjs

in pages/reader.js, I have

```
Reader.getInitialProps = async ({query}) => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/books/reader/' + query.id);
    const json = await res.json();
    return {book: json}
};
```

Unfortunately, that overwrites the cookies stored in the request object on the backend. When I do a `console.dir(req.cookies)` in the backend node js, express code, I get **undefined** in book.js where the reader code is.

How can I fetch without overwriting the request object in the express backend?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the example in https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/auth0

In the file [ssr-profile.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/auth0/pages/advanced/ssr-profile.js) it shows how you can forward your cookies in the request to the server:

```
  // To do fetches to API routes you can pass the cookie coming from the incoming request on to the fetch
  // so that a request to the API is done on behalf of the user
  // keep in mind that server-side fetches need a full URL, meaning that the full url has to be provided to the application
  const cookie = req && req.headers.cookie
  const user = await fetchUser(cookie)
```